# making a modular d3js tree node

Tags: d3.js

I've grabbed a d3js tree node sample from http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

What I want to achieve is to make this modular so that I can have multiple of them in the html.
Javascript supports functions inside functions, so I just put the code inside a draw function, but it distorts the chart without any error.
Any ideas how to fix it?

```css
.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
.node text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="treenode_container_id1"></div>
  <div id="treenode_container_id2"></div>

<script>
function draw(id, data){
    var TREENODE_DURATION = 750;
 var margin = {top: 10, right: 10,
      bottom: 10, left: 100};

 var width = 1200;
 var height = 200;

 var root;
 var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([height, width]);
 var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

 var svg = d3.select("#" + id).append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .attr("id", "svg_" + id)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 root = data[0];
 root.x0 = height / 2;
 root.y0 = 0;
 update(root);
 d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "200px");
 
 function wrap(text, width) {
   // wraps long labels given the maximum width
   // where words are split by spaces
   text.each(function() {
  var text = d3.select(this),
   words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
   word,
   line = [],
   lineNumber = 0,
   lineHeight = 0.7, // ems
   y = text.attr("y"),
   dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"))/2,
   tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 10).attr("y", y+20).attr("dy", dy + "em");
  while (word = words.pop()) {
    line.push(word);
    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
    if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
   line.pop();
   tspan.text(line.join(" "));
   line = [word];
   tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
    }
  }
   });
 }

 function update(source) {
   // Compute the new tree layout.
   var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

   // Normalize for fixed-depth.
   nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

   // Update the nodes…
   var i;
   var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

   // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
  .on("click", click);

   nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

   nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

   // Transition nodes to their new position.
   var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(TREENODE_DURATION)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

   nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

   nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);
   

   // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
   var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(TREENODE_DURATION)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

   nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

   nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

   // Update the links…
   var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

   // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
   link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
   var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
   return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    });

   // Transition links to their new position.
   link.transition()
    .duration(TREENODE_DURATION)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

   // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
   link.exit().transition()
    .duration(TREENODE_DURATION)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
   var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
   return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .remove();

   // Stash the old positions for transition.
   nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.y0 = d.y;
   });
 }

 // Toggle children on click.
 function click(d) {
   
   if (d.children) {
  d._children = d.children;
  d.children = null;
   } else {
  d.children = d._children;
  d._children = null;
   }
   update(d);
   
 }
}

// +++++ Generate 2 drawings:
var data1 = [{"name":"Top Level","parent":"null","children":[{"name":"Level 2: A","parent":"Top Level","children":[{"name":"Son of A","parent":"Level 2: A"},{"name":"Daughter of A","parent":"Level 2: A"}]},{"name":"Level 2: B","parent":"Top Level"}]}];

var data2 = [{'name': 'food', 'parent': 'null', 'children': [{'name': 'vegetables', 'parent': 'food', 'children': [{'name': 'mint', 'parent': 'vegetables'}, {'name': 'asparagus', 'parent': 'vegetables'}, {'name': 'eggplant', 'parent': 'vegetables'}, {'name': 'avocado', 'parent': 'vegetables'}, {'name': 'braccoli', 'parent': 'vegetables'}]}, {'name': 'fruits', 'parent': 'food', 'children': [{'name': 'apple', 'parent': 'fruits'}, {'name': 'orange', 'parent': 'fruits'}, {'name': 'banana', 'parent': 'fruits'}]}]}];

draw("treenode_container_id1", data1);
draw("treenode_container_id2", data2);
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the initial value to `i`, so every node is getting an `id` of `NaN`.

`var i = 0;`